# EasyMock expectations within loop

Tags: java, junit, easymock

Is it possible to set different expectations for a mock which is being invoked in a loop?

Considering the use case,

```
while(condition){
   List list = Database call //Call to be mocked
   ....
   Logic based on above response
}
```

how can we set expectations such the first iteration returns a list of objects, while the second call returns empty list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
expect(mockDatabase.call()).andReturn(object1).once();
expect(mockDatabase.call()).andReturn(object2).once();
replay(mockDatabase);
```